# Dynamic chart codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, chart.js

I have a table (name recuperare_laborator )with those columns: subject_id; uploader_id; class_id; and timestamp. I want to count all files from day by day from all table so I make this code:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT subject_id ,uploader_id, class_id, COUNT(*) FROM recuperare_laborator  GROUP BY class_id');
                     foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
                            {
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['class_id'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                              }
```

And this code work only to counter per class. How I made to count All project from one day?
I need to see:

```
    Day 1 100 count
    Day 2 101 count
...
```

And with this information I want to make a dynamic chart.
I try to make but i don't know how to implement code.

```
    <script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: ['1','2'], //here i need day 1,day 2...
      datasets: [{
          data: [  '10','20'], // here i need count from day 1, count from day 2
          backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(67, 148, 255, 0.2)',

          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(67, 148, 255, 1)',

          ],
          borderWidth: 1
      }]
  },
});
</script>
```

The result must be:
[image chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afY8d.jpg)

[picture with line count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3sS1.png)

Comment: did you solve this issue??

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: You want to get aggregate of each class in datewise right?..means data for class 1 and class to for today should be considered as different count ..am I correct?

Comment: I want to count all files submitted today, tomorrow... Etc. And with data to "generate" a chart.

Comment: Then if 2 entries are there for 2 classes for today... Does it show count 2?

Comment: yes. The code what i show works very good only for: class 1: 100 entry; class 2 101 entry. But i don't know how to show : 01.01.2020 50 entry; 02.01.2020 51 entry.

Comment: Add your db schema too...you can use dbfiddle

Comment: Why did you grouped by class_id...you told u need only count of entries irrespective of class id right..?

Comment: I don't know how to group by date. I try to change GROUP BY class_id' with GROUP BY timestamp' but the result is one line with 565 entry. I want to count from all classes all files submitted and group by date then implemented on chart .

Comment: File counting by day does not matter what class it belongs to. For example, if on 04.05.2020 we have 15 files from class 1 and 2 files from class 2 the result should be:
04.05.2020 17 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@myEDU,

You need to alter your query with grouping by `DATE(timestamp)`

Here the **[SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h9troCRfa4c7D5b8jPGYjo/1)** as per your requirement.

I'm adding dynamic integration with php here in single controller including view,data manipulation as well as DB call, Codigniter follows MVC pattern and you need to split this to a MVC pattern.

> Line chart expects data for one month in array and label too and that
>   we are serving through arrays `$datasetarr` and `$datasetlbl`
>   respectively.

***[Chart.js DOC](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)***

**Dynamic Integration**

```
public function index() 
{ 

  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
        <title>Chart</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body> 
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">

              <?php
              $datasetarr = array(null);
              $datasetlbl = array(0);

              $month = date("m");
              $mname = date("F");

              $start = $end = strtotime(date("Y-m-01"));

              $this->load->database();
              $query = $this->db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) AS cnt, DATE(`timestamp`) AS dt FROM `recuperare_laborator` AS t1 GROUP BY dt HAVING MONTH(dt) = "'.$month.'" ORDER BY dt ASC');
              $res = $query->result_array();

              if($res){
                $count_dt = array_column($res, 'dt');
                $count_array = array_column($res, 'cnt');
                $maxdt = max($count_dt);

                //need to pass the month no in which you need.For eg: 05. Here i'm passing current month.
                while ( $start <= $end ) {

                    $cdate = date('Y-m-d', $end);                
                    $key = array_search($cdate, $count_dt);                
                    if($key !== false){                  
                      $datasetarr[] = (int)$res[$key]['cnt'];
                    }else{
                      $datasetarr[] = 0;
                    }
                    $datasetlbl[] = date('d', $end);
                    $end = strtotime("+1 day", $end);

                    if( max($count_dt) < date('Y-m-d', $end) || $month != date('m', $end)){
                      break;
                    }
                }

                $datasetlbl[] = date('d', $end);
                $datasetarr[] = null;

              ?>
              <table class="table table-striped">
                 <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <td>count</td>
                     <td>date</td>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                   <?php
                    foreach ($res as $row)
                    {
                      echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['cnt'] . "</td>";
                      echo "<td>" . $row['dt'] . "</td>";
                      echo "</tr>";
                    } 
                   ?>
                 </tbody>
              </table>

              <canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas> 
              <?php 
              } 
              ?>                     
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){

        <?php if($res){ ?>
        new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($datasetlbl); ?>,
            datasets: [{ 
                data: <?php echo json_encode($datasetarr); ?>,
                label: "<?php echo $mname; ?>",
                borderColor: "#515fcf",
                backgroundColor: "#515fcf",
                fill: false
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: 'Activity report 01 - <?php echo date("d", $end); ?>'
            },
            elements: {
              point:{
                  radius: 0,
                  hoverRadius: 5
              }
            },
            scales : {
                xAxes : [ {
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: 'Day'
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false
                    }
                } ],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: 'Number of files submitted'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        max: <?php echo (ceil((max($count_array)) / 10) * 10)+10; ?>,
                        min: 0,
                        stepSize: 10
                    }
                }]
            }
          }
        });
        <?php } ?>              

      });            
      </script>    
  </body>
  </html>
  <?php    
}
```

**Static Chart**

```js
$(function() {
  new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line', data: {
      labels: [0, "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17"], datasets: [ {
        data: [null, 21, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, null], label: "May", borderColor: "#515fcf", backgroundColor: "#515fcf", fill: false
      }
      ]
    }
    , options: {
      title: {
        display: true, text: 'Activity report 01 - 17'
      }
      , elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0, hoverRadius: 5
        }
      }
      , scales: {
        xAxes: [ {
          display: true, scaleLabel: {
            display: true, labelString: 'Day'
          }
          , gridLines: {
            display: false
          }
        }
        ], yAxes: [ {
          display: true, scaleLabel: {
            display: true, labelString: 'Number of files submitted'
          }
          , ticks: {
            max: 30, min: 0, stepSize: 10
          }
        }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>count</td>
            <td>date</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>2020-05-01</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2020-05-02</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>2020-05-06</td>
          </tr>
<tr>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>2020-05-08</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2020-05-16</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If you want to fetch particular months data with MySQL query and want to avoids data manipulation process with PHP code, you can use the following query. Here you just need to pass month and year to the query in different places.In this query im fetching data for 2020 May. Added in [Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h9troCRfa4c7D5b8jPGYjo/2) too

[Ref](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month)

```
SELECT t1.*, COUNT(t2.id) AS cnt  FROM (SELECT dt
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAKEDATE('2020',1) +
        INTERVAL ('05'-1) MONTH +
        INTERVAL daynum DAY dt
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t*10+u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
    ) AA
) AAA
WHERE MONTH(dt) = '05' ORDER BY dt) AS t1 LEFT JOIN `recuperare_laborator` AS t2 ON dt = DATE(`timestamp`) GROUP BY dt HAVING MONTH(dt) = '05' ORDER BY dt ASC;
```

Comment: That whole `while()` block needs some serious re-thinking -- I don't think I'd keep any of that.  Starting with the variable naming (why is "end" the variable that increments?) and progressing to why so many variable calls are made and why you are using `array_search()` versus temporary keys w/ `isset()` and why not use a do-while loop if you are going to unconditionally enter the loop on the first pass AND write a break condition at the end of your loop.  Too much to fix.  Why not group by the month() in the query?!?  No active record?